# Add firebase in side-panel app (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm adding firebase into my side-panel app in manifest V3. Here is how i deal with the code:

In service_worker (background.js):

```
    const firebaseConfig = {
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    console.log(firebase);
```

which shows I've initialized the app successfully.

In app.js ,

```
    button.addEventListener('click',function(){
    login();
    });
    
    function login(){
       e=email.value;
       p=password.value;
       firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(e,p);
    }
    console.log("working");
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
    if(user){
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: "landing.html"});
        });
    }else{show.innerHTML="User is not defined";
    
    }
    });
```

However, I kept getting the error:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been
> created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

Anyone knows why?

Comment: I strongly doubt that a firebase init in a service worker has any effect on the rest of the extension that doesn't run in the service worker. They don't share any memory and have different lifecycles. If this is true, then you need to init firebase outside the service worker.